# Skip apt-get update

Tags: apt

After punching in `sudo apt-get update` everything starts updating and stops at `0% [Connecting to mega.nz (154.53.224.162)]`.

`Mega.nz` is banned in my country(Kazakhstan) and I believe that's why I can't update it. I installed Ubuntu just a couple of days ago for the first time. What should I do?

Comment: I think it's because you have a PPA update set from Mega. P.S. Why is Mega banned?

Comment: @Bharadwaj Raju Yes, I have a Mega sync client installed. I have no idea why it is banned. There are plenty of websites that can't be accessed without TOR or VPN or proxy (imgur, torproject.com, etc ). I guess it has to do something with preventing terrorism.

Comment: You can disable the entry which says 'Mega' or something in the Software Sources app - but then you won't receive any updates to the Sync Client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you can't (or just don't want to) try to bypass the ban with something like a [new DNS server](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/), you'll have to remove that repo from your system.
Keep in mind that after doing this, you won't be able to update any MEGA-related packages.

1. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and remove any line containing a link to `mega.nz`.
2. If there wasn't any, go to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` instead (it's a directory) and remove any file that contains *"mega"*.
3. Try to `sudo apt-get update`. You shouldn't have any problem now.